# SharePoint 2010 - Change favicon for a SiteCollection

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

It is possible to change the favicon in the adressbar for a SiteCollection?
I want to change the icon only for one SiteCollection in our environment.
Is there a PowerShell Command? I don´t want to use the SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the MasterPage that you're using.

In the OOTB masterpages it's controlled by the line:

```
<SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/_layouts/images/favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my problem is that I want to change the favicon only from one SiteCollection in my Farm. Do you know any solution for that problem?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. Either copy v4.master and create a custom master page that points to a different icon for your site collection or open v4.master in SharePoint Designer and create an unghosted version that points to a different icon. Either way, you need a master page for your site collection that points to something other than /_layouts/images/favicon.ico.